# How do I multiple select in mysql using one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an sql statement like this:

```
Select Id,Name From table where id = var
Select Id,Name From table where id = var
Select Id,Name From table where id = var
```

I was able to a multiple select in one query but it's only allows one column per select.

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   user_table
    ) AS tot_user,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   cat_table
    ) AS tot_cat,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   course_table
    ) AS tot_course
```

Comment: Why? Even using a `union` query would still run the underlying queries individually, gaining nothing in real efficiency terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**join**](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php) if tables relates each other else
use [**union**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of [subselect](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node17.html)s, [unions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) or [joins](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/l/aajoins2.htm) - it depends on what you're trying to do:

Answer (score 0):

`SQL joins are used to query data from two or more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these tables.`

For instance:

```
SELECT user_table.name, user_table.email, cat_table.title
FROM user_table
FULL JOIN cat_table
ON user_table.cat_id=cat_table.id
ORDER BY user_table.id
```

More to read at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp